# Как настроить imagick локально на windows 7

Tags: imagick

Как настроить  imagick локально на windows 7 ?
погуглил везде пишут что нужно установить программу затем разместить библиотеку php_imagick.dll и прописать в php.ini extension=php_imagick.dll
я все это сделал но как расширение этот класс не распознается
везде пишут о версиях 6.8 ..
а на сайте загрузки только 6.9... версии
пожалуйста кто то если подключал imagick на windows 7 64-bit c vc6 PHP 5.3.5 на xampp помогите советом как подключить
Cпасибо большое заранее!

Answer (score 1):

Страница загрузки релизов imagick, есть все версии для Windows

http://www.imagemagick.org/download/windows/releases/